# SQL*Loader Control File Custom Date Format

Tags: oracle, toad, sql-loader

I need to import from a CSV file in which timestamps are given in the following format

```
2014-06-14T09:38:29
```

I tried the following in the control file for SQL*Loader but it doesn't work

```
TIME DATE "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS"
```

and

```
TIME DATE "YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS"
```

How can I parse this custom date? The error I get is

```
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code

```
time date 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24MISS'
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm, just that it should be `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'`